# automatically add function to function array in R

Tags: r

all the functions receives the same argument, I want to run all the functions on a same data, so I created *manually* list of functions:

```
foo_1 <- function(data){
  .
  .
}

foo_2 <- function(data){
  .
  .
}

foo_3 <- function(data){
  .
  .
}
```

than: `funcs <- c(foo_1, foo_2, foo_3)`

the downside of this approach is if I create a new function, say `foo_4` i need to manually add this function to `funcs` vector. is there any way to this kind of think automatically ?

Comment: If you don't add the new function to a vector or list, then how else could it be added?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I was thinking of having all the funcs in one file, than somehow import all the functions in that file. (saving order/name). or create functions without names directly inside vector. or some sort of design pattern. I just want to see what this community advice in that case. The point is that all I have to do is write the function, and all the other code remains the same.

Comment: It seems, that comment is essential for understanding your question. Could you include it in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first put your functions into a file from which to source them back in ...

```
# creating the source file for the functions 

funcs_text <- 
"
foo_1 <- function(data){}
foo_2 <- function(data){}
foo_3 <- function(data){}
"

fname <- tempfile()
writeLines(funcs_text, fname)
```

Now we can read in the file via `source()`. The trick is to first create an new environment (`new.env()`) where the functions defined in the file are sourced into. This environment is passed to `source()` via the `local` argument. Thereafter we transform the environment to an list - et voila.

```
# reading in file
funcs <- new.env() 
source(fname, local=funcs)
funcs <- as.list(funcs)
```

Now you can further use your list of functions to do your processing.

```
# accessing a function

funcs[[1]]
funcs$foo_1
funcs[["foo_1"]]


# calling a function

funcs[[1]]()
funcs$foo_1()
funcs[["foo_1"]]()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could go beyond `source()` and actually make a package for these functions, that way you get the benefit of having rich documentation for them—i.e. :

```
#' Multiply x by 2
#'
#' Spiffy long description here
#'
#' @param x the data
#' @return atomic numeric value
#' @export
f1 <- function(x) { x * 2 }

#' Divide x by 2
#'
#' Spiffy long description here
#'
#' @param x the data
#' @return atomic numeric value
#' @export
f2 <- function(x) { x / 2 }

#' Subtract 3 from x
#'
#' Spiffy long description here
#'
#' @param x the data
#' @return atomic numeric value
#' @export
f3 <- function(x) { x - 3 }
```

Put those in and build a package called `myfuncs` then you can do something like:

```
library(myfuncs)
library(purrr)

lsf.str("package:myfuncs") %>% 
  invoke_map_dbl(list(x=100))
```

You can just use `invoke_map()` if you don't care about type safety or are returning more complex objects than what `purrr` supports out of the box.

You can add non-exported functions to that package as well if you ever need supporting functions for your exposed functions.

Answer (score 1):

By your example, your functions are enumerated and with a pattern. Then you can use a combination of [`grep`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) and [`lsf.str`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/ls_str.html). We finally use `get` to get the function calls in a list.

```
foo_1 <- function(data){
    data*2
}
foo_2 <- function(data){
    data*3
}
bar <- function(data){
    data+22
}

## Vector output of functions that match string
funcs_names <- lsf.str()[grep("foo_",lsf.str())]  

## Get function calls
funcs <- sapply(funcs_names,get)
funcs
## $foo_1
## function (data) 
## {
##     data * 2
## }
## 
## $foo_2
## function (data) 
## {
##     data * 3
## }
```